# VB.NET decimal value from Datagridview update into SQL table - formatting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I've got a problem when trying to update an sql record, taking the value from `DataGridView` after the user alter the cell value. Inside the table the value to be modified is a `decimal(18,8)`, when I try to insert a value such as 50.55 inside the `DataGridView`, then is updated inside the Sql table as 5055.00.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Show code how you updating data to sql database

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ValueType` for the row and you should be good to go! For example, in your SQL table, the column `decimal(18,8)` is a number that has 10 digits before the decimal and 8 digits after the decimal thus you need to format your DGV columns as follows (as an example):

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N8"  

DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
```

For more info read this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95e7e7ef-2e71-412f-abe5-ffbee2c12c18/how-to-format-datagridview-columns-to-numeric-columndefaultcellstyleformat-does-not-work?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: Hi sir,

first of all thank you very much for your kind answer. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work for me, the DGV still shows the incorrect value.

Comment: Maybe this issue has something to do with the use of COMMA instead of point when displaying and changing values of the DGV.

Comment: How are you binding the data from the database on to your DGV? Can you at least show that part of the code please?

Comment: Of course. Inside a method used to load and refresh the DGV, I do:

Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = TADO.ExecuteDataset(GetConnectionString, CommandType.Text, sql_query).Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Comment: ExecuteDataset is a custom command that returns a dataset representing the table, result of a "select...from" query.

Comment: Hi, the update still doesn't work, as the number it's shown with 8 decimal digits but when I change the value of the cell, the value inserted as nn.dddddddd or something like that with less decimals, after the update query is triggered and the datagridview is refreshed, instead of showing, for istance, 50.25, the grid shows 5025,00000000 which is the only thing I do not understand why is happening.